# how to call class object to perform search in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have text boxes to search for data, and 6 text boxes to display data if the data I am looking for is found. 
I'm trying to use an object class to make the code in the form look a little neat. the class is named ClsSearch. This is the class code snippet:

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string txtCode { get; set; }
        public string txtBarcode { get; set; }
        public string txtUnit { get; set; }
        public string txtQty { get; set; }
        public string txtCost_price { get; set; }
        public string txtSales_price { get; set; }

string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbLearn"].ConnectionString;
        public void X001_TextChanged()
        {
                MySqlConnection mysqlconn = new MySqlConnection(mainconn);
                string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tb_stock_product WHERE Item_Name='" + Name + "'";
                MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, mysqlconn);
                mysqlconn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader sdr;
                sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtCode = sdr.GetString("Code");
                txtBarcode = sdr.GetString("Barcode");
                txtUnit = sdr.GetString("Unit");
                txtQty = sdr.GetDouble("Qty").ToString();
                txtCost_price = sdr.GetInt32("Cost_price").ToString();
                txtSales_price = sdr.GetInt32("Sales_price").ToString();
            }
            mysqlconn.Close();
```

then I tried calling the class in the form, exactly when the button was pressed, and this is the code:

```
private void X_001_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connection_Frm_Ordering load = new Connection_Frm_Ordering();
            load.X001_TextChanged();

            load.Name = X_001.Text;

            load.txtCode = X_002.Text;
            load.txtBarcode = X_003.Text;
            load.txtUnit = X_004.Text;
            load.txtQty = X_005.Text;
            load.txtCost_price = X_006.Text;
            load.txtSales_price = X_007.Text;
        }
```

but the code i made is not working.. can anyone help me where is the error ? 
sorry if this code might be messy, I'm still learning :)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also, you should be parameterizing your SQL queries.

Comment: maybe because you are reasigning the model properties with the empty values from your  textboxes, do you need it the other way around

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the code i made does nothing when i will do a data search using a text box.

Comment: @spzvtbg mmm.. i don't know, i just do what i know because i'm still learning.. can you tell me how to code right ? :)

Comment: I mean you should put X_002.Text = load.txtCode instead of load.txtCode = X_002.Text and so on for all load (obj) properties. You already set the load.txtCode value from the db result and then set it back to blank from the textbox.

Comment: try to call load.X001_TextChanged(); at last.

Comment: @spzvtbg ok.. i will try your suggestion..

Comment: In the design.cs file the controls are private.  You can either make public or create an interface for each control that is public so your instance can access the control.